# Message label in Rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, msmq

MSMQ messages have a [Label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703250(v=vs.85).aspx) property. It can contain an application-defined string describing the message. Does Rabbitmq have such a concept? Maybe it's called differently - haven't found anything similar yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use custom message headers. They are a lot more flexible than the MSMQ label. You can store string, number or boolean, or a list of those values.

Add custom headers to the IBasicProperties (C# example)

```cs
var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
properties.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();
properties.Headers.Add("Label", "some text");
```

When you consume, extract them from the IBasicProperties.